# Weird WCF exception: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I'm using .NET 4.0 to create a WCF webservice which is hosted on IIS 7.0. Everything seems to be fine except a weird WCF exception as below.

```
    Message       : The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
Stack Trace   : Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

From the first glance I thought that, it should be some thing related to message size, therefore I've adjusted my binding configuration:

```
<binding 
    closeTimeout="00:01:00"
    openTimeout="00:01:00"
    receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
    sendTimeout="00:01:00"
    allowCookies="false"
    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
    maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
    messageEncoding="Text"
    textEncoding="utf-8"
    transferMode="Buffered"
    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas
        maxDepth="2147483647"
        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>

<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
        </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work as I expected. Another idea came, I thought it should be something related to IIS configuration, so I changed my web.config as following:

```
    <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
    <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"></customErrors>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="10800" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
  </system.web>
```

Unfortunately none of changes above help me solve my issue. I still see that weird WCF exception at the client site. Below is the client binding:

```
<binding name="myClientBinding"
             closeTimeout="00:10:00"
             openTimeout="00:10:00"
             receiveTimeout="01:00:00"
             sendTimeout="01:00:00"
             allowCookies="false"
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             messageEncoding="Text"
             textEncoding="utf-8"
             transferMode="Buffered"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas
        maxDepth="21474836"
        maxStringContentLength="21474836"
        maxArrayLength="21474836"
        maxBytesPerRead="21474836"
        maxNameTableCharCount="21474836" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

Any ideas about what is going on with WCF & IIS...!

Comment: WCF debugging is never fun. I recommend a read through [Easing the pain of WCF debugging](http://davybrion.com/blog/2008/08/easing-the-pain-of-wcf-debugging/), which will teach you avout the `.svclog` file and the Service Trace Viewer tool.

Comment: Can you post your service/endpoint elements on how they look in the config? As well which binding are you using would be helpful.

Comment: Is it possible that there is an unhandled exception in your service code? This is the error you would see in such a scenario.

Comment: Well, the funniest thing is: there's no exception occurring in the service itself...!

Comment: The connection is getting closed at Request level only. So the service  is not invoked.Try increasing closeTimeout time out at client level. And also check whether right service Url is used.

Answer (score 0):

The connection is getting closed at Request level only. So the service is not even invoked.

1. Try increasing value of closeTimeout at client level.
2. Use client.Close(); to close the client connection of every instance after usage.
3. Check that the uri of the service is correct.